# distutils byte-compiling error in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils, distutils2

I have a package that can be installed in python 3 using a distutils based `setup.py` with the command

```
python setup.py install
```

but gives a `SyntaxError` in python 2. Is there a way to skip the byte-compilation of this particular module or try to catch the `SyntaxError` exception (using try/except pass did not work)? I would like to have the package installed in python 2 and it does not matter that this module in the package will not work.

```
byte-compiling ../
    a, b, *c = d
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That particular syntax is not valid in Python 2 so you need to find a way to exclude the module or disable the byte compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary solution was to skip writing of bytecode files with the `-B` option.

```
python -B setup.py install
```